# Offline mode is not working when using NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I am currently a newbie to iOS development and trying to get the cache policy (*NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad*) to pull from the cache to view a web page while being in offline on the iPhone (using airplane mode). I am currently using the Reachability API provided by Apple to figure out if the network/wifi connection is up and running or not.  This works fine but when I go to airplane mode I am not getting a webpage to populate the UIWebView.  Any suggestions would very helpful, I look around online but did not find much helpful links.  Thanks.

The code is below:

```
*- (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender 
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_entry.articleUrl]; 
    NSURLRequest *webRequest = nil;

    NSString *articleUrl = [_entry.articleUrl substringFromIndex:7];

    NSArray *myArray = [articleUrl componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"]];

    NSString *hostUrl = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%@", hostUrl);
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:hostUrl];

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:1024*1024*10];

    // Verify current help file cache if we have network connection...
    if (netStatus == ReachableViaWWAN || netStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) 
    {
        webRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];   
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Network NOT reachable - show (local) cache if it exists
        webRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad timeoutInterval:30];
    }

    [_webView loadRequest:webRequest];
}*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `UIWebView` does not persist web page cache. I have never done this but using [AFCache](https://github.com/artifacts/AFCache) should work for cache persisting.

Also make sure you got the cached page in place. If the webpage is not cacheable (i.e. with Pragma: no-cache), `UIWebView` might still not cache it.